# Stereoisomers of Hexachlorocyclohexane

Tags: nomenclature, stereochemistry

What is the basis of naming the various isomers of hexachlorocyclohexane $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, etc.? [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexachlorocyclohexane) is a list of these isomers. Is it just random naming, or is it according to some convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn’t find anything definite. However, I found a [PDF](http://www.lubw.baden-wuerttemberg.de/servlet/is/16833/stoffbericht_hch.pdf?command=downloadContent&filename=stoffbericht_hch.pdf) from the [State’s Institution for Protection of the Enviroment in Baden-Württemberg (*Landesanstalt für Umweltschutz*)](http://www.lubw.baden-wuerttemberg.de/) which gives me two or three relevant clues. Along with my intuition and a chat with a labmate, I conclude:

There is nothing systematic or conventionalised in the names of the isomers. They were likely named after the order in which they were isolated or their structures were determined.

Clues I used:

- The $\unicode[Times]{x3B6}$, $\unicode[Times]{x3B7}$ and $\unicode[Times]{x3B8}$ isomers were synthesised last.
- $\unicode[Times]{x3B1}$, $\unicode[Times]{x3B2}$ $\unicode[Times]{x3B3}$ and $\unicode[Times]{x3B4}$ were characterised first by a guy called Teunis van der Linden, after whom the active insecticide $\unicode[Times]{x3B3}$-hexachlorocyclohexane was named *lindane*.
- Thereby concluding that $\unicode[Times]{x3B5}$ was discovered after $\unicode[Times]{x3B1}$ to $\unicode[Times]{x3B4}$.